# Android asynctask with no input or output

Tags: android, soap, wsdl

I have set up an async task that will get a list of countries from a wsdl and from the result i create a bunch of country objects and add the objects to an arraylist in the country class file.

I want to be able to run this async task that will populate the array list then from another view be able to call specific indexes from the array list based on what the user has selected.

i have tried creating a class that extends AsyncTask and i have inserted the same code from the gingerbread version of the app i created which worked fine because network actions could be ran from the main thread

```
The type getWSDL2 must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncTask.doInBackground(Object...)
```

i dont have any objects to pass to this i all variables and stuff to get the wsdl data is within the async task and all the data i need from it is assigned to the arraylist from within the async task.

```
public class getWSDL2 extends AsyncTask {

    protected void doInBackground() 
    {
       ........
    }
```

Comment: How about passing null in the varargs parameter? Either way you will override the doInBackground() method, so you can handle the null.

Answer (score 0):

Pass Void... as a parameter for doInBackground

```
protected void doInBackground(Void... params) 
{
   ........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question you're not sure how to implement the `AsyncTask` because you have no need to pass values into it. All of the variables and data you need are included within the code that will execute the transaction with your server to download whatever it is you intend to display.

public class getWSDL2 extends AsyncTask {

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
        //All I/O code here   
    }     

    protected Void onPostExecute(){
        //Anything that needs to run on the UI thread here
    }
```

}

The general structure of the `AsyncTask` is listed above. The `doInBackground` method must contain any I/O functions while any thing you do tha touches a view, i.e. displaying the results of you're query as saved in a array list, must be called from `onPostExecute`, which runs on the UI thread.

From what I gather the solution is simple. Put all the code that is required for your server transaction within the `doInBackground` method. If you need to display the results of that transaction in a view just add a return statment to `doInBackground` and include the type of object/variable you will return in the varargs listed for the `AsyncTask`. For example if you were going to display the result of an `ArrayList` generated in your `doInBackground` method

public class getWSDL2 extends AsyncTask {

```
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) { 
        //All I/O code here
        return nameOfArrayListYouBuild   
    }     

    protected Void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> whatever){
       //use ArraList whatever to display your stuff
    }
```

}

In the alternative if you don't need to display anything or run any functions on the UI thread then don't use the `onPostExecute` method at all.

public class getWSDL2 extends AsyncTask {

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
        //All I/O code here
        return null   
    }
```

}

You can structure you're task so that it just uses `doInBackground`